# regex lookbehind alternative for parser (js)

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, lookbehind

#### Good morning

**(I saw this topic has a LOT of answers but I couldn't find one that fits)**

I am writing a little parser in javascript that would cut the text into sections like this :

```
var tex = "hello   this :word is apart"

var parsed = [
  "hello",
  "   ",
  "this",
  " ",
  // ":word" should not be there, neither "word"
  " ",
  "is",
  "apart"
]
```

the perfect regex for this is :

```
/((?!:[a-z]+)([ ]+|(?<= |^)[a-z]*(?= |$)))/g
```

But it has a **positive lookbehind** that, as I read, was only implemented in javascript in 2018, so I guess many browser compatibility conflicts... and I would like it to have at least a **little compatibility**...

I considered :

- trying capturing groups (?:) but it consumes the space before...
- just removing the spaces-check, but ":word" comes in as "word"
- parsing the text 2 times, one for words, the other for spaces, but i fear putting them in the right order would be a pain

Understand, I NEED words AND ALL spaces, and to exclude some words.
I am open in other methods, like not using regex.

#### my **last option** :

removing the spaces-check and organising my whole regex in the **right order**, praying that ":word" would be kept in the "special words" group before anything else.

#### my **question** :

would that work in javascript, and be **reliable** ?

I tried

```
/(((:[a-z]+)|([ ]+)|([a-z]*))/g
```

in https://regexr.com/ seems to work, will it work in every case ?

Comment: Your second regex has one too many left parenthes.

Comment: I agree, it was to make groups, but i don't know if it's worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're open to non-regex solutions, but I can give you one that includes both. Since you can't rely on lookbehind being supported, then just capture everything and filter out what you don't want, words followed by a colon.

```js
const text = 'hello   this :word is apart';
const regex = /(\w+)|(:\w+)|(\s+)/g;
const parsed = text.match(regex).filter(word => !word.includes(':'));

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! exactly the solution i was working on, but much simpler.

Comment: and your solution highlights that no matter the order, regex will take ... the longest group ?

Comment: Not at all, those are three different capture groups. The first finds just groups of letters, the second finds a colon followed by a group of letters, and the last one matches just spaces.

Comment: after many attempts, it does seem to me that regex matches group by order :  /(some regex)|(.+?)/g makes everything that is not "some regex" the second group, but if I invert the groups everything is in the lazy group, even the "some regex" matching points....

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2 regexes, first one matches the Words, you DON'T want and then `replace` them with an `empty string`, this is the simple regex:

```
/:\w+/g
```

Then `replace` with an `empty string`. Now you have a string, that can be parsed with this  regex:

```
/([ ]+)|([a-z]*)/g
```

which is a simplified version of your second regex, since forbidden Words are already gone.

Comment: thanks ! I'm working on something of this kind, first parsing the text to classify words then parsing words again to keep those I want...   thank for the \w ! does it work everywhere ?

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge, \w Works everywhere, it's very basic

Comment: Yes, \w is fully supported in JavaScript, as is \d for digits and \s for space